# Datatable sort not working with custom data types

Tags: lightning-web-components

I tried creating a lightning-datatable with custom data types, but unfortunately when trying to sort a column, it does not work. I have set the columns to sortable: true but still it does not work.

Component structure

```
c-main-component
    |---> c-custom-datatable
```

[image]

One thing i noticed though, it highlights the first cell when i tried to sort it.

[image]

Comment: Did you implement the sorting logic on your side? Only setting sortable=true on the columns definition is not enough, that only lets you "sort" on the column header but the you have to write your own sorting logic for it to work. The datatable doesn't know how you want your data to be sorted on its own.

Comment: hi joacoiudica. yes i implemented it as well. 

i copied the sortBy and onHandleSort in the documentation

Comment: please, add all your code that is relevant to your problem on your question so I can see what you did. I can't give you an answer without any code

Comment: Please add your sort code and also mention if Start date and end date are treated as String or date while sorting?

Comment: Hi guys. thank you for your replies. Here is a playground link emulating the scenario: https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/cNzxx3E7cL6AQggK7dai

The behavior is that when you click the sort, you can only do it two times then it stops sorting to either asc or desc

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It is my fault. A good night sleep really helps.

I have a property declared as:

```
sortedBy = 'contractId';
sortedDirection = 'asc';
```

Im consuming it in the template as:

```
    <c-custom-datatable
        key-field="id"
        columns={columnsToPass}
        data={recordToShow}
        sorted-direction={sortedDirection}
        sorted-by={sortedBy}
        onsort={onHandleSort}
        hide-checkbox-column>
    </c-custom-datatable>
```

When I hit the sort I utilized the event handler:

```
onHandleSort(event) {
    const { fieldName: sortedBy, sortDirection } = event.detail;
    const cloneData = [...this.recordToShow];

    cloneData.sort(this.sortBy(sortedBy, sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1 : -1));
    this.recordToShow = cloneData;
    this.sortDirection = sortDirection;
    this.sortedBy = sortedBy;
}
```

My mistake was on the event handler

```
    this.sortDirection = sortDirection;
```

It should be:

```
    this.sortedDirection = sortDirection;
```

Comment: A piece of advice, whenever you can't find the reason as to why some code you wrote is not doing what you expect, ALWAYS check for sintax mistakes or spelling errors/confusions. This won't happen just once, so keep that in mind. Happy coding

Comment: Thanks for the advice joacoiudica! appreciate it